# Why does IPv6 host route gets lost the second time I run "nmcli device reapply port1"?

Tags: command-line, network-manager

I set the IPv6 address of `port1` with `nmcli`:

```
/usr/bin/nmcli connection modify port1 ipv6.method manual ipv6.address 1510::2/64  
/usr/bin/nmcli device reapply port1
```

The first time I run this, the IPv6 host route is right:

```
1510::2/128
```

But running the `/usr/bin/nmcli device reapply port1` command a second time, the host route `1510::2/128` is lost in `route -A inet6`, as shown in the image:

[image: outputs of terminal commands]

Now if I run the command:

```
nmcli device connect port1
```

the host route `1510::2/128` will reappear in `route -A inet6`.

Why is the IPv6 host route lost when I execute `nmcli d reapply port1` a second time?

Comment: Why ask here?  You've provided no OS, product or release details that give clues as to what software stack you're using. You also show text (server?) which doesn't use network-manager  - so what you using?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *The version you give is only used by EOL releases of Ubuntu*

Comment: WSL:Ubuntu20.04；nmcli tool, version 1.22.10；5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: When I excute "nmcli connection modify c1",   how can I do the modify work?    nmcli connection up c1;   or   nmcli device reapply d1?